# Import process stuck migrating 30+ GB WordPress site from S3 bucket to AWS (Fargate) serverless WordPress evironment

Tags: import, amazon, docker

I'm in the midst of migrating a wordpress.com hosted site that is in the vicinity of 35 GB to AWS infrastructure via an S3 bucket.

On AWS we are running a multi-zone WordPress configuration with an application load balancer in front (so there is no direct ftp access to the WP instance).

We are using the All-in-One S3 Client plug-in (paid subscription) which hasn't been successful thus far.

Exporting the .wpress file from the WP admin console works fine however, importing it from S3 onto a base WordPress instance ("latest", launched from Docker container) is stuck progressing beyond looping between "retrieving a list of WordPress files..." and "Done retrieving a list of all WordPress files" every few minutes.

We have allocated sufficient CPU, disk and memory resources so there is no bottleneck on the AWS side and also confirmed that a smaller import works as expected.

Does anyone have a recommendation on different approaches or other tools that have been successful in this sort of scenario (and/or with 30-50 GB WordPress sites?).

Thanks.